# how to verify text color in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

I am working on selenium IDE, Wihout enter mandatory fields value click on submit button. Mandatory fields should highlighted in red color.Any body have idea about how to verify these label which are highlighted in red color? please reply

Answer (score 1):

By using below code, you will get the color of the label, which you can use to verify

```
driver.findElement(By.id(“id“)).getCssValue(“font-color”);
```

For Selenium IDE

1. Using CSS identifiers, try retrieving the color attribute for your
   toolbar.
2. Simply assert for the presence of that element, using the
       color as the descriptor.

Here's an example: For the webpage, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp, the assertion for the Red color would be

```
assertTrue(selenium.isElementPresent("css=td[bgcolor=#ff0000]"));
```

Comment: Thanks Kapil, but I am working in selenium IDE , do you have any idea about how to verify font color in IDE?

Comment: I am using selenium IDE in which verifyAttribute command is used to verify the color as commad: verifyAttribute Target: id=labelname@class         
 value= labelerror